# Finding the size MongoDB aggregate queries results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We often run into the max size limit 16 megabytes for our aggregate queries. We are looking for a way to find the estimated size required to run a particular query for one document. So that we can optimize and tune our queries before going to production.

Is there any way to find the in memory size used by a mongoDB aggregate command. I came across [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504) jira defect, the last comment is confusing. Is it really fixed? Also i am not sure if profiling would give us what we are looking.

Are there any mongodb profiler available that is similar to VisualVM for java?

Are you guys aware of solutions to tackle this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That sounds complex. The coming version returns aggregate results as cursors instead (http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#rn-2-6-aggregation-cursor), and since 2.5.3 was 'feature complete' and 2.5.4 was 'QA complete' (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversions-panel), I don't think the 2.6 release will take much longer. No guarantees, but maybe you can save the effort.

Comment: Not sure if we would be able to upgrade. That would be too much of effort. We are running 2.4.4.

Comment: Well, I haven't had any trouble upgrading mongodb before. Copy binaries, restart, done. Also, what would a profiler help? You can't profile errors, only successful queries. The problem is that you need to know the rough size of the result set in advance.

Comment: Yea, it's about willingness to take risk, with terabytes of data. We don't want to do that, unless there is a real need.